# Hash table's finding function in c?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

The question is from the book,Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in c.When talking about hash table,the author show the finding function like this:

```
Positon find(ElementType Key,HashTable H)
{
    Position CurrentPos;
    int CollisionNum;
    CollisionNum=0;
    CurrenPos=Hash(Key,T->TableSize)
    while(H->TheCells[CurrentPos].info!=Empty&&H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element!=key)
    {
        CurrentPos+=2*++CollisionNum-1;
        if(CurrentPos>=H->TableSize)
            CurrentPos-=H->TableSize;
    }
    return CurrentPos;
}
```

The author said that the order of the judge condition in `while` sentence,

```
H->TheCells[CurrentPos].info!=Empty && H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element!=key
```

is very important and shouldn't be exchanged. But I don't know why. I have tried to exchange the order, but the function still work correctly. What bug will happen if I exchange the order?

Comment: What are the members of the `TheCells[CurrentPos]` structure? How is this structure defined?

Comment: BTW, the first condition **has** to be evaluated before the second condition. It definitely has something to do with that. (If the first one applies, the second one is **not** evaluated. It's called short-circuit evaluation.)

Comment: In general, you can't switch the operand of a short-circuit operator. But I don't see any trouble here.

Comment: TheCells is a pointer pointing to the array,which store the element

Comment: The only issue I can see is if `Element` can potentially have a trap value, so that just comparing it with another value would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you write multiple conditions like `condition1 && condition2 && ...`. These are evaluated from left to right. If any of these conditions evaluate to false, the remaining conditions to the right will not be evaluated.

Now you haven't provided us with sufficient information about the structures used in your code, but it seems reasonable to assume that the `.info` for a cell contains `Empty` if the `.Element` for that cell has not been initialized.

If we write

```
H->TheCells[CurrentPos].info!=Empty && H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element!=key
```

then we would first be checking whether or not the `.Element` has been initialized. Only if it is, do we move on to comparing its value to `key`. If it isn't, then `.Element` will never be accessed.

But if we write

```
 H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element!=key && H->TheCells[CurrentPos].info!=Empty
```

there could be problems. Let's assume that `.Element` for the current cell has not been initialized. The first condition accesses `.Element` to compare it to `key`. This would likely lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Without further details, my guess would be that if `H->TheCells[CurrentPos].info` is `Empty`, then `H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element` is meaningless (maybe not initialized?), thus evaluating it would lead to error.

Here is a (somewhat silly/extreme) example of such pattern:

```
char *dst = NULL;
if (dst != NULL && memcpy(dst, "foo", strlen("foo" +1))) // this is OK
    // do stuff
memcpy(dst, "foo", strlen("foo" +1)); // segfault here!!!
```

Here is some (less silly) pseudocode to get the idea:

```
if (something.has_a_value == true && something.value == value_I_look_for)
    // then proceed
```